# Looking for a short story about the perfect beer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was about a man working at a brewery that accidentally made the perfect beer. The man may have been in advertising. He starts to notice that the heads on the beers are taking shape, so he pours out enough for the foam to form a goddess, or spirit, of beer.

I'm confident that it appeared in a science fiction magazine in the 50s or 60s.

Comment: ...And what does she do?

Comment: That is it! Many thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might be "[The Beautiful Brew](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57706)" (1954) by James E. Gunn.  First published in *Beyond Fantasy Fiction*, September 1954.

> It was the essence of beer captured in a glass. The hucksters, for once, couldn’t possibly oversell it. The clear, pale yellow had a sparkling brilliance; tiny bubbles streamed delicately to the top.

> Something had piled the foam high in the center of the schooner and sculptured it into the shape of a girl. She began at the waist, a perfect, three-inch replica, her arms raised, her hands smoothing long, foam hair.

> This time a foam hand seemed to reach out to meet his hand. He jerked it back. The foam came with him; the girl came with the foam, stepped out of the yellow pool as if she had legs, standing on the pavement as if she had feet. Her creamy chest rose and fell. Her eyes opened. They were deep blue, like a summer sky mirrored in a mountain pool.

You can read the entire story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Beyond_Fantasy_Fiction_v02n02_1954-09_cape1736/page/n5/mode/1up).

Comment: And then there's the Henry Kuttner story about the perfect beercan opener.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron I know that one too! "The Proud Robot" :)

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron I was just thinking about that story yesterday. And I haven't  spoken of it or heard it mentioned in thirty years.

Comment: It was one of the first SF stories I read. When I think of all the first editions that library had...